# Is my laptop overheating?

Tags: laptop, cooling, overheating

I'll start with the TL;DR part:

**TL;DR**

- HP TX1000's WiFi stopped working one day. Then it began to (suddenly) turn itself off.
- When "cool", it turns on and I get bios but it turns off after 5-6 seconds.
- If I turn it on right afterwards I'd get no bios/post or anything, just a black screen (not even backlight at all) and it would sit like that for any amount of time, it won't turn off suddenly. Fan is at full speed but no overheating/hot air coming out of the vent can be felt though.
- If I turn it down and let it that way for about 10-15 minutes it'd turn on again (with bios and everything) but it'd turn itself off after 5-6 seconds again and it goes on like that.

Is this a temperature related problem? Would cleaning it completely solve this issue? or is it broken already?

**Edit:**

- I cleaned everything thoroughly and replaced the thermal compound
- Now it turns on everytime correctly but shuts down at boot.

Here's a video that pictures this issue in its latest state: [HP TX1000 Series boot failure](http://videobam.com/wfzqU)

**Update**:

It turns out that it **wasn't overheating**, the problem was a **faulty** BIOS or motherboard that would make the computer turn off itself just at the moment it tries to **boot** from any device.

Comment: That sounds really fast for just generally overheating. You should definitely try to open it (or get someone to open it who knows what he's doing - generally the better idea unless you're "that one") and check the fans. Even while being full of dust I'd say it shouldn't overheat that fast, unless there's some serious cooling issue (like coolant/fan disconnected from the CPU for whatever reason). Also, while doing this, are you on battery or is it plugged in?

Comment: I've already checked the fan and the thermal compound and they are ok, I let it stay at the BIOS for 5/10 minutes and it didn't shut down or anything, temp was still normal, but at the moment I tried to **boot** from a live stick it suddenly shut down, I tried again with the hard disk and even tried without any drive at all and the result was the same: It shuts down trying to boot an OS. It's getting a lot stranger. What could be the cause? Is it a faulty firmware? (Somehow it now turns on correctly at the 1st attempt - no blank screen at all)

Comment: Might be some hardware problem screwing up something. What if you try to disable as many onboard-devices as you can in BIOS?

Comment: It has its defaults set: Dedicated video mem. 32 MB, Virt. Tech. Off, CD-ROM, Floppy and Internal adapter boot are all off. I also have to say it lists drives perfectly, it just shuts down trying to boot any of them.

Comment: As you said your WiFi stopped working, I'd suggest try disabling that, then try again. If it isn't cooling (check temperatures in BIOS), then it sounds like some hardware fault you probably can't fix on your own.

Comment: There isn't anything connected to the mobo other than the LCD, the power supply, an USB Stick and the VGA cable on the output. I will post a video for the sake of information (and to help other people who may stumble upon the same issue). It seems as a weird firmware problem.

Comment: I thought your WiFI is onboard. Is it USB?

Comment: Here it is: [link](http://videobam.com/wfzqU)
As you can see, the problem is the boot. Maybe I'll have to replace the mobo.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14483/discussion-between-arielnmz-and-mario)

Comment: Definitely not overheating imo, although I'm out of ideas right now. You should add the video link to your initial question though.

Comment: IMO its either a failing MOBO or dud RAM. When you boot it'll start loading data from the drive into your RAM, and if a stick is failing that could cause it to powercycle.

Comment: There is only one 512 MB stick inserted (which I use to test computers). It has passed 100% the memtest86+ (made on another computer) test so I don't think RAM is failing (maybe the slots are?). I don't know. Also, it powers off just as it _tries_ to boot, not while loading the OS so I wouldn't blame RAM at all, the bios is loaded at RAM too and it works (it uses much less RAM though).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out that it **wasn't overheating**, the problem was a **faulty** BIOS or motherboard that would make the computer turn off itself just at the moment it tries to **boot** from any device.

Comment: Lol, how come you downvote my own answer?